# getting objectid from set of object ids

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymongo

i'm trying to loop through a set of objectid's from mongodb.

```
print agent_ids
```

yields a set of ids:

```
...ObjectId('542de00c763f4a7f558be133'), ObjectId('542de00c763f4a7f558be130'), ObjectId('542de00c763f4a7f558be131')])
```

The following loop:

```
for agent_id in agent_ids:
    print agent_id
```

yields:

```
...
542de00c763f4a7f558be133
542de00c763f4a7f558be130
542de00c763f4a7f558be131
```

How can get `agent_id` from the loop to including `ObjectId()`?

Comment: Actually, I was not very sure when I answered the question. Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) function:

```
for agent_id in agent_ids:
    print repr(agent_id)
```

Will return

```
ObjectId('542de00c763f4a7f558be133')
ObjectId('542de00c763f4a7f558be130')
ObjectId('542de00c763f4a7f558be131')
```

The reason this works, is because by default when printing each element in the list, the instance will be converted to its string representation before being printed out - when you call the `repr` function, a custom representation is printed:

Per the docs:

> A class can control what this function returns for its instances by defining a **repr**() method.

When printing the list in your original example, it used the `repr` representation for every element in the list, and therefore we need to mimic that behaviour.